# How to format tick labels to geo location format with python Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am working with geo json and i have successfully drown a map according to geo json file with matplotlib and it show latitude and longitude as floating point notation such as 7.6 etc.

but my requirement is x and y axis tick labels should be format as below format.I searched in documentation but i haven't found good solution.Is there is any possible way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Because the earth is not a disc, you wouldn't normally plot a map in a cartesian coordinate system. Instead a projection is usually used. We do not know about the projection you use here. But if you have a function that maps 7.6 to whatever you want to show (which isn't specified in the question either) you can use a `FuncFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found an answer for this question. This kind of geo coordinates generation is not an easy task. then i substitute custom labels instead of thick values by using this.

```
labelsx = [item.get_text() for item in ax2.get_xticklabels()]
labelsx[1] = u'79°30\'0"E'
labelsx[2] = u'80°0\'0"E'
labelsx[3] = u'80°30\'0"E'
labelsx[4] = u'81°0\'0"E'
labelsx[5] = u'81°30\'0"E'
labelsx[6] = u'82°0\'0"E'
ax2.set_xticklabels(labelsx)
```

this not may be a good answer but , when thick labels represent same values this method is possible like this. That's why i used it here.